# Get specific types of object array to a new array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have my object:

```
struct Person {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
}
```

I have added some persons to an array:

```
let p1 = Person(name: "Tony", age: 10)
let p2 = Person(name: "Lisa", age: 20)
let p3 = Person(name: "Anna", age: 30)
let p4 = Person(name: "Morgan", age: 40)
let p5 = Person(name: "Jane", age: 50)

let persons = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]
```

I want all the names in a separate array but I don´t want to do like `nameArray.append(p1.name)`... Is it any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply `map` the name:

```
let names = persons.map({ $0.name }) // ["Tony", "Lisa", "Anna", "Morgan", "Jane"]
```

Comment: Worked fine thanks!

Comment: @JaneDoe If you think an answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: Just to add to this, the `map` method is basically a shortcut to looping through the collection, performing actions on each element, and then appending a result to a new `Array`. Here’s a [good guide](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/) on it and also `filter` and `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `map` function:

```
let names = persons.map { $0.name }
```

This may look like magic, so let's expand this to see what exactly is going on:

```
let names = persons.map ({
    person in
    return person.name
})
```

What happens here is that `map` applies a "transformation" to each `Person` in the array. And you specify what transformation to do by passing a closure to the `map` function. Here you say that "when you give me a person, I give you back the name of the person". See the transformation here? We transformed a person to just a name! `map` automatically applies this to every item in the array and appends all the results of the transformations to a new array.